# Backslash syntax when creating objects

Tags: php, namespaces

The path in require and require_once is like (dir1/dir2/test.php).
Can we create objects the same like `$obj= new class1/class2;`?
If yes, please explain.

http://php-fedex-api-wrapper.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htdocs/example1.php

```
$rateRequest = new ComplexType\RateRequest();
```

Comment: This post explain the backsalsh in great detail http://stackoverflow.com/q/4790020/6521116

Answer (score 12):

It is not using the path, it is using the [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) (`ComplexType`); a feature built-into PHP 5.3.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

If however, you want to autoload certain classes, take a look at [`__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) magic function.

> Many developers writing
>   object-oriented applications create
>   one PHP source file per-class
>   definition. One of the biggest
>   annoyances is having to write a long
>   list of needed includes at the
>   beginning of each script (one for each
>   class).
>
> In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary.
>   You may define an __autoload function
>   which is automatically called in case
>   you are trying to use a
>   class/interface which hasn't been
>   defined yet. By calling this function
>   the scripting engine is given a last
>   chance to load the class before PHP
>   fails with an error.

**Example:**

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2();
```

Answer (score 3):

\ is the namespace operator in php 5.3, it is sort of a logical compartment for classes and functions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php