# What does a \ (backslash) do in PHP (5.3+)?

Tags: php, namespaces, opcode, opcache

What does a `\` do in PHP?

For example, [CSRF4PHP](https://github.com/foxbunny/CSRF4PHP/blob/60d9172b7f0cd93346cac9065fb17182854ebf1c/CsrfToken.php#L80-L87) has `\FALSE`, `\session_id`, and `\Exception`:

```
public function __construct($timeout=300, $acceptGet=\FALSE){
    $this->timeout = $timeout;
    if (\session_id()) {
        $this->acceptGet = (bool) $acceptGet;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Could not find session id', 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 337, accepted):

`\` (backslash) is the namespace separator in PHP 5.3.

A `\` before the beginning of a function represents the [Global Namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

Putting it there will ensure that the function called is from the global namespace, even if there is a function by the same name in the current namespace.

Comment: is it safe to remove it if my server is causing an error?

Comment: PhpUnit likes to use it :)
\var_export()
if (\defined('PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL')) {;}

Comment: But why is there a backslash before `FALSE`?

Answer (score 40):

**Namespaces**

In PHP 5.3+ the backslash `\` symbol is used in namespaces. It is the start symbol to indicate a namespace and also serves as a separator between sub-namespace names.

See official documentation about
**[namespacing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)**.

**Opcache**

Additionally in PHP 7.0+ some functions are *replaced with opcodes* by *OPCache*, which makes these specific functions run a lot faster. However this only works when the functions are placed in the root namespace. See this **[discussion](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/3048)** about this topic. So besides namespacing, the `\` indirectly also affects code optimisation.

The following native functions benefit from this effect:

```
"array_slice"
"assert"
"boolval"
"call_user_func"
"call_user_func_array"
"chr"
"count"
"defined"
"doubleval"
"floatval"
"func_get_args"
"func_num_args"
"get_called_class"
"get_class"
"gettype"
"in_array"
"intval"
"is_array"
"is_bool"
"is_double"
"is_float"
"is_int"
"is_integer"
"is_long"
"is_null"
"is_object"
"is_real"
"is_resource"
"is_string"
"ord"
"strlen"
"strval"
```

Comment: If it cause codes run faster wondering why wouldn't they apply it by default ? who doesnt like performance?

Comment: Probably because OPCache wasn't configured by default for a long time, and the feature wasn't even included until version 7. It also requires knowledge to set up and [configure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php).

Answer (score 33):

To clarify potential confusion:

The backslash **does not** imply **class inheritance**.

In the following, `Animal`, `Dog`, `Shepherd` don't have to be classes, but simply [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384204/what-are-namespaces). Meaning something used to group names together to [avoid naming collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3384384/1678614).

```
$myDog = new \Animal\Dog\Shepherd\GermanShepherd();
```

The leading `\` means `Animal` was declared in the global scope.

Answer (score 10):

The `\` is used in PHP 5.3 for namespaces. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php for more information on namespaces and PHP.