# Laravel "Unexpected data found" error when trying to change format of Carbon created_at date

Tags: laravel-4, php-carbon

When I try to modify the format of the default created_at field of my Resource model, I get the following error:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "type":"InvalidArgumentException",
      "message":"Unexpected data found.
                 Unexpected data found.
                 The separation symbol could not be found
                 Unexpected data found.
                 A two digit second could not be found",
      "file":"\/var\/www\/html\...vendor\/nesbot\/carbon\/src\/Carbon\/Carbon.php",
      "line":359
   }
}
```

Here is the code that produced the above error:

```
$tile = Resource::with('comments, ratings')->where('resources.id', '=', 1)->first();
$created_at = $tile->created_at;
$tile->created_at = $created_at->copy()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone)->format('F j, Y @ g:i A');
```

If I remove `->format('F j, Y @ g:i A')` from the above code, it works fine, but it's not in the format I want. What could the problem be? I have almost identical code elsewhere in my app and it works without error.

**UPDATE:**
Using `setToStringFormat('F j, Y @ g:i A')` does not cause an error, but returns `null`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding the following code to my model worked for me:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    if(Auth::check())
        return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->copy()->tz(Auth::user()->timezone)->format('F j, Y @ g:i A');
    else
        return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->copy()->tz('America/Toronto')->format('F j, Y @ g:i A');
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('F j, Y @ g:i A');
}
```

This allows me to use `created_at` and `updated_at` in the format I want.

Answer (score 6):

I did experience the same problem, and in my search for an answer I stumled across [How do you explain the result for a new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450644/how-do-you-explain-the-result-for-a-new-datetime0000-00-00-000000) .

I decided to change the datetime-columns in the database to nullable with default value = NULL, to prevent fields from having value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

My migration in laravel 5 looks like this:

```
Schema::table('table', function($table)
{
    $table->dateTime('created_at')->nullable()->default(null)->change();
    $table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable()->default(null)->change();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not a carbon issue, it's a conflict between a `setAttribute` or `getAttribute` in your model.

Answer (score 3):

You needed to parse given date before saving
user this code

```
Carbon::parse($request->input('some_date'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to change the format of `created_at`.  It has to be a Carbon object.  If you want to display the `created_at` date in a different format, then just format it at the time you output it.  Or you may want to create a method that changes the format so you can call it whenever you want it in a different format.  For example, add a method like this to your Resource class:

```
public function createdAtInMyFormat()
{
   return $this->created_at->format('F j, Y @ g:i A');
}
```

You can also have that function adjust the timezone, etc.  Then you can use `$tile->createdAtInMyFormat()` for example to get your special format `created_at` from your `$tile` object.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I added my own answer with code which worked better for me.

Answer (score 1):

first add this to your model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'start_time' => 'time:h:i A',
    'end_time' => 'time:h:i A',
];
```

and then you can further format it with either Carbon or other Php native functions, such as
`date('h:i A', strtotime($class_time->start_time))`  // "09:00 AM"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and it was simply a matter of uses dashes instead of slashes.

```
$model->update(['some_date' => '2020/1/1']); // bad
$model->update(['some_date' => '2020-1-1']); // good
```

Reminder: If you specify your dates on your model, Eloquent is smart enough to convert it for you.

```
protected $dates = [ 'some_date' ];
```