# Change date output format, using Laravel and Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

The MySQL database stores time in `Y-m-d H:i:s` i.e `2000-12-32 00:00:00` format , UTC.

I am wondering if there's some way I can convert the created_at dateTime property on the `$order` objects returned from the database, so it would instead send a `dateTime` string to the client as such: `31/04/16 14:25pm` and without seconds.

```
for($i = 0;  $i < sizeof($orders); $i++ ) { 
    $orders[$i]->created_at = $orders[$i]->created_at->format('d/m/y H:i');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Welcome to Accessors and Mutators:

Proper way of doing this using Laravel is by defining an **Accessor**:
The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of your fields.
This means that you don't have to loop over a set of objects and then convert the values, simply define an **Accessor** in your model and you're good to go.

### Solution #1:

So for your date field add the following method to your `Orders Model`

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d/m/y H:i a');
}
```

The name of an Accessor should be `getFieldAttribute` where you replace field with your corresponding column name.
This way you don't have to loop over the results.

Note:
do bare in mind that by doing so, you are now getting the created_at as a string not a Carbon object anymore in your model, so how can this affect you? if you're doing some comparison somewhere else, you can also use a **Mutator** to set the field value more on **Accessors** and **Mutators** can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators

### Solution #2:

Yeap, basically loop over all of your array and do the conversion.

```
for($i = 0;  $i < count($orders); $i++ ) {
    $orders[$i]->created_at = $orders[$i]->created_at->format('d/m/y H:i a');
}
```

### Update:

if you're experiencing errors like "The separation symbol could not be found" or "Unexpected data found."
adjust the solutions like this:

**Solution #1:**

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value->toDateTimeString())->format('d/m/y H:i a');
}
```

**Solution #2:**

```
for($i = 0;  $i < count($orders); $i++ ) {
    $orders[$i]->created_at = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $orders[$i]->created_at->toDateTimeString())->format('d/m/y H:i a');
}
```

Comment: I am giving the basic loop approach a go. However it won't accept conversion to any format other than its Y-m-d H:i:s one. So for created_at->format('d/m/y H:i a') it will throw up errors such as: Carbon.php Unexpected data found.. a two digit second could not be found etc. trailing symbol .. separation could not be found etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer, also the reason for the errors you isn't because Carbon doesn't allow you to format properly, it's because it really met unexpected data.

Comment: Also check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223958/laravel-unexpected-data-found-error-when-trying-to-change-format-of-carbon-cre

Comment: Still gives me the unexpected data errors (two digit second could not be found)... then if I add the :s in the ->format argument it will then pick on the 'a' and state trailing data. So unless the input format and convert to format are identical, it gives me errors. The time in the database looks as such '2016-04-01 13:53:54', so input format looks correct ?

Comment: I've updated the code in the update section to convert to a date time string first, check it. and regarding that database comment, you will probably find a cell with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 that's what causing the error by the way.
if you want to fix that set the created_at null flag, and default value to null in the table structure.

Comment: Same thing occurs with solution #2. Unexpected data found.
A two digit second could not be found. I have confirmed all dates in the database have two digits representing seconds if that matters.

Comment: how about you wrap the function in a try catch statment like this
`for($i = 0;  $i < count($orders); $i++ ) {
try{
    $orders[$i]->created_at = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $orders[$i]->created_at->toDateTimeString())->format('d/m/y H:i a');}
catch(\Exception $ex){
dd($orders[$i]);
}
}`
this way you can see the value that was passed that caused the error.

Comment: It appears to give  Model->fromDateTime('31/03/16 12:33 pm') ,   Model->asDateTime('31/03/16 12:33 pm'), Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '31/03/16 12:33 pm')

Comment: By the looks of it createFromformat function won't work because there's in fact no seconds value in the time string for some reason.

Comment: Based on the feed back I suggest you try this `for($i = 0;  $i < count($orders); $i++ ) {
    $orders[$i]->created_at = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $orders[$i]->created_at->toDateTimeString())->format('d/m/y H:i a');
}`

Comment: If that :s is taken off the input format in createFromFormat, Error log reads : at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2016-03-31 12:33:38'), if the :s is put on like before 'Y-m-d H:i:s', it states: at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '31/03/16 12:33 pm')  After copy pasting your last suggestion, I only get one error: Trailing data

Comment: the problem is your records are inconsistent, some have the seconds and some dont, you can run a query that will update the cells that have seconds and remove them, then use the last suggested function, otherwise run a query that would set the seconds to 00 if they're not found and use the default function, this is as far as I can help :)

Comment: Thanks for trying. Albeit I only have like five records I am testing with and all created_at fields are consistent with the aforementioned format, all have seconds on the end. The database wouldn't even let me enter a different format if I wanted to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108826/discussion-between-islam-al-rayan-and-laserbeak).

Answer (score 0):

you are right,you can format created_at time

```
foreach($orders as $order){
echo $order->created_at->format('d/m/y H:i a');
}
```

Comment: Can format, but it appears can't assign to $order->created_at   , that is not safe, just transform for the response.

Comment: Because it's echoing the result, use a for loop like the one in the OP to assign.

Comment: @IslamAl-Rayan Well, I am. Won't assign formatted dateTime and Carbon spits errors out. Echo works though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$orders` is an eloquent model, the `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes are automatically converted to carbon instances, so you can already run carbon methods on them.

See the docs on this topic: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

So, your code:

```
$orders[$i]->created_at->format('d/m/y H:i');
```

Should work just fine!

You could always add a helper method in your `Order` model to make it a bit more readable too, something like this:

```
public function createdAtTimeStamp()
{
    return $this->created_at->format('d/m/y H:i');
}
```

Then you can access it like so:

```
$orders[$i]->createdAtTimeStamp()
```