# How to import data from CVS file to table in SQL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, encoding

I want to import data from a csv file to my students table in sql.

my csv file format:

> 28; 2; umair; 11/4/2019; 2; islam; muslim; pk; rent; 1234567891;
> 11/21/2119; 111111111111; 11/20/2019; 1222; 11\11\2019; 11/28/2019;
> 11/20/2019; ; ; ; active; yes; yes; 11/11/1100; 11/11/0000;

every word is in a cell in excel file.

my code in StudentController.php

```
public function importCsv()
{
    if (($handle = fopen ( public_path () . '\students.csv', 'r' )) !== FALSE) {
        while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 1000, ',' )) !== FALSE ) {
            $csv_data = new Student();
            $csv_data->id = $data [0];
            $csv_data->bus_id = $data [1];
            $csv_data->grade_id = $data [2];
            $csv_data->teacher_id = $data [3];
            $csv_data->room_id = $data [4];
            $csv_data->name = $data [5];
            $csv_data->dob = $data [6];
            $csv_data->gender = $data [7];
            $csv_data->religion = $data [8];
            $csv_data->ethnicity = $data [9];
            $csv_data->nationality = $data [10];
            $csv_data->guardian_residency_type = $data [11];
            $csv_data->applicant_qid_no = $data [12];
            $csv_data->qid_validity = $data [13];
            $csv_data->applicant_visa_no = $data [14];
            $csv_data->visa_validity = $data [15];
            $csv_data->passport_no = $data [16];
            $csv_data->passport_expiry = $data [17];
            $csv_data->session_start_date = $data [18];
            $csv_data->estimated_graduation_date = $data [19];
            $csv_data->bus_service = $data [20];
            $csv_data->bus_pickup = $data [21];
            $csv_data->bus_dropoff = $data [22];
            $csv_data->created_at = $data [23];
            $csv_data->updated_at = $data [24];
            $csv_data->deleted_at = $data [25];
            $csv_data->save ();
        }
        fclose ( $handle );
    }
}
```

I am calling importCsv function through a button in my view file:

```
<a href="{{ url('admin/auth/student/importCsv') }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">Import as CSV</a>
```

The students.csv is already stored in the public directory of the project with the data in it.

I keep on getting different errors every time I refresh with whatever possible change I think is necessary but now I'm stuck. The latest error is

```
Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. A two digit minute could not be found
```

I think it's all due to some sort of format error but I have taken the data from the database as a sample which is working totally fine when added through the backend by user.

Comment: Hi @Fahad, welcome to stackoverflow. i noticed that you assign a value to `created_at` value at `$csv_data->created_at = $data [23];`. you should parse the date time properly, see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25224316/4648586). see if it helps.

Comment: If i dont add created_at or any date format then it should run right? However if i want to add these date times then i should create a custom method for format changing or whatever...

Comment: my bad, not adding the method. my point is to parse the input using [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), maybe `Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/yyyy', $data[23])` works.