# How to handle MySQl null dates returning '-0001-11-30 00:00:00'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

When my MySQl dates are null, PHP returns them as '-0001-11-30 00:00:00'.

I know this is because I am using Europe timezone but how can I handle this?

I keep getting:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Unexpected data found.
in Carbon.php line 425
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '-0001-11-30 00:00:00') in Model.php line 2915
```

How can I fix this?

Mick

NB: This is different from :
[How do you explain the result for a new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450644/how-do-you-explain-the-result-for-a-new-datetime0000-00-00-000000)

It is different because I am asking what I am supposed to do about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you explain the result for a new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450644/how-do-you-explain-the-result-for-a-new-datetime0000-00-00-000000)

Comment: It's nothing to do with timezones (European or otherwise), and all to do with how PHP's DateTime will interpret an empty date value

Comment: Great, so how do I prevent the error?

Comment: I guess that you will have to write a function that recognizes null values *based on the timezone* and set em to null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basing on this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075291/4499267 at point 8) it says that

> MySQL stores "0000-00-00 00:00:00" if you set a datetime column as NULL, **unless you specifically set the column to allow null when you create it**.

So that might be the solution, to create the table with a nullable datetime column

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I still get the same error, when I try to turn the collection into an array: in Carbon.php line 425
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '-0001-11-30 00:00:00') in Model.php line 2915
at Model->asDateTime('-0001-11-30 00:00:00') in Model.php line 2435
at Model->attributesToArray() in Model.php line 2412
at Model->toArray() in Collection.php line 969

Comment: Could you post the script that generates the error? Try also to `var_dump()` the value that MySQL returns

Comment: Just:  //products is an Elastiquentcollection and needs to be an array

        $arrProducts = $products->toArray();

Comment: I got it. If your date column didn't allow nulls, mysql stored them as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Now if you changed it in order to allow nulls, those value are still `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. You'll have to manually set them to `NULL`

Comment: I deleted all the rows, amended the db, then added the rows again. However! I am using Elastic Search and I had to delete the index and then add all the records again. Looks like it is working! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will avoid this problem in future by always allowing nulls.