# What are the date doundaries in PHP

Tags: php, date

I use several date functions with dates around the French republic of 1792-1806.

But I want to know if the (php8) date function can handle these dates.

```
function CheckFrDate($CheckDate){
  $BeginFrDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '22/09/1792');
  $EndFrDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '22/09/1806');
  if (
    $CheckDate->getTimestamp() > $BeginFrDate->getTimestamp() && 
    $CheckDate->getTimestamp() < $EndFrDate->getTimestamp()){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return -1;  
  } 
}
```

So a date like 23/09/1793 should be ok. But my function keeps returning false.

Comment: Works for me. https://3v4l.org/ZkSlZ Are you using a very old and 32-bit version of PHP?

Comment: FYI: please also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450710/367456 and then especially the last lines, but for France IIRC this could be of interest.

Comment: Your function never returns false, it returns either 1 or -1, both of which evaluate to boolean true. I suggest you check the logic around how you are using this function, and also return proper boolean values. PHP works fine with nearly any date you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

If a date function returns false, you are able to get the real (verbose) error message by calling `var_dump(date_get_last_errors());`

read more:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-get-last-errors.php

Comment: I think that by: _"But my function keeps returning false."_, the return value -1 is meant, and not a real "false" value. Note the warning on [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php): _"**Warning**

-1 is considered **true**, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!"_

Comment: Documentation says the return type is `DateTime|false` so `-1` is not valid as return type.

Comment: I agree the question is confusing, but nowhere does it say that _a date function_ returns false. I don't think any real attempt to debug has been done.

Answer (score 0):

I'd dare say that PHP date ranges do not have hard-coded limits, probably just the integer size or some similar platform limit. However, not all input mechanisms work the same way. For [example](https://3v4l.org/QHitu):

```
$years = [
    -25000,
    0,
    9999,
    10000,
    25000,
];
foreach ($years as $year) {
    $dt1 = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', "22/09/$year");
    $dt2 = new \DateTime();
    $dt2->setDate($year, 9, 22);
    var_dump($year, $dt1, $dt2);
    echo "\n";
}
```

```
int(-25000)
bool(false)
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(28) "-25000-09-22 16:16:09.918321"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}

int(0)
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "0000-09-22 16:16:09.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "0000-09-22 16:16:09.918367"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}

int(9999)
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "9999-09-22 16:16:09.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "9999-09-22 16:16:09.918415"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}

int(10000)
bool(false)
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "10000-09-22 16:16:09.918451"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}

int(25000)
bool(false)
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(27) "25000-09-22 16:16:09.918476"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

In particular, [date_create_from_format()](https://php.net/date_create_from_format) reports this:

```
date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', "22/09/25000");
print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

```
Array
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [10] => Trailing data
        )

)
```

This happens because, as [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php), `Y` format code is:

> A full numeric representation of a year, up to 4 digits

Regarding [your specific code](https://3v4l.org/AWWuL), it appears to work as expected:

```
function CheckFrDate($CheckDate){
    $BeginFrDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '22/09/1792');
    $EndFrDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '22/09/1806');
    if (
        $CheckDate->getTimestamp() > $BeginFrDate->getTimestamp() &&
        $CheckDate->getTimestamp() < $EndFrDate->getTimestamp()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

$CheckDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '23/09/1793');
var_dump(CheckFrDate($CheckDate));
```

```
int(1)
```

I no longer have a 32-bit Windows system to test but, if I recall correctly, \DateTime interface was never affected by the 1970 Unix Epoch limit. However, if you use `->getTimestamp()` to obtain a Unix timestamp, you'll get an integer that will be.

You can drop Unix time altogether:

```
function CheckFrDate($CheckDate)
{
    $BeginFrDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '22/09/1792');
    $EndFrDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '22/09/1806');
    if ($CheckDate > $BeginFrDate && $CheckDate < $EndFrDate) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```