# What does backslash do as prefix to a function name?

Tags: php, namespaces

Preparing for the ZEND-Exam, I found a question where a class redefined the strlen-function:

```
namespace MyFramework\MyString
{
  function strlen ($str) 
  {
    return \strlen($str) * 2; // return double string-length
  }

}
```

I never came across that "\function"-thing before and could not get an explanation from my trainer - can somebody pls. help shed some light...?

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4790020/57091

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduced in PHP 5.3, `\` is a namespace separator.

In your example, the outer strlen is MyFramework\MyString\strlen, the inner strlen is the global one.

> Without any namespace definition, all class and function definitions are placed into the global space - as it was in PHP before namespaces were supported. Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is required from the global space even in the context of the namespace.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Answer (score 8):

It calls a function from the global namespace.

You need it only if there's a function of the same name in the current namespace.