# php function to get page title

Tags: php, function, page-title

I want to get my website page title through a function

First I get the Page Name from a function...

```
function pagetitle() {
global $th, $ta, $tp, $ts, $tc; // <---- Getting the variable value from outside function
global $bl, $qt;
$tit = ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));
if($tit == "Index") {
    echo $th;
}
elseif($tit == "About-us"){
    echo $ta;
}
elseif($tit == "Projects"){
    echo $tp;
}
elseif($tit == "Services"){
    echo $ts;
}
elseif($tit == "Contact-us"){
    echo $tc;
}
elseif($tit == "Blog"){
    echo $bl;
}
elseif($tit == "Quotation"){
    echo $qt;
}
```

}

Then I tried to get the page title in the format of PageName | PageTitle  or PageTitle | PageName...

```
function getOrg_title(){
$tit = "";
$block = " | ";
global $sl;
$org = $sl['app_org'];
if($sl['title_before'] === 'yes'){
    $tit = $org.$block.\pagetitle(); //<----- This should be like "Raj | This is my website"
}  else {
    $tit = \pagetitle().$block.$org; //<----- This should be like "This is my website | Raj"
}
echo $tit;
}
```

But not happening...

```
$tit = $org.$block.\pagetitle(); //<----- Output is "This is my websiteRaj |"
```

And

```
$tit = \pagetitle().$block.$org; //<----- Output is "This is my website | Raj"
```

What should I do ?

Comment: This code doesnt look like php

Comment: @Filype care to explain? looks php to me

Comment: Unless you are going to parse your own PHP/HTML files to get the page title you are not going to get it serverside. You can get it from the DOM using Javascript and pass it to a PHP program.

Comment: @mlewis54 I am trying it in my index.php page. So it should give the output.

Comment: got confused with you concat `.` notation and namespacing `\\`

Comment: I am also about '\' but netbeans automatically generates it or suggesting to do that. However, PLZ answer me if you have.

Comment: I'm not sure you are able to concat an ECHO value to non-printed sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expect `pagetitle()` to [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) the page's title, but instead in your code you use [`echo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).
`echo` will print out the title to the client rather than return it to the caller.

So change you `echo $...;` to `return $...;` and do `echo pagetitle();` whereever you use it directly.

If this can not be done, you could extend your function to

```
pagetitle($echo = true)
{
    // ...
    if(/* ... */) {
        $ret = $th;
    } elseif(/* ... */) {
        $ret = ...;
    } elseif(/* ... */) {
        $ret = ...;
    }
    // And so on ...

    if($echo)
        echo $ret;

    return $ret;
}
```

Now in your wrapper function call `pagetitle(false)` to prevent the `echo` and still get the title from it.

---

**About the backslash:** `\pagetitle()`
The [backslash is the namespace separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3). Since you are not using namespacing here, all functions will be on the *root namespace*.
In this case - if you are using PHP 5.3 or above - you can use it or leave it out.

Comment: Hi Lukas, I have done as per your instruction but there is a new problem. I am getting the output like `PageTitlePageName | PageTitle` if the database field set to 'yes' otherwise the output is `PageTitlePageTitle | PageName`.

Comment: Then you either did not replace all `echo`s in `pagetitle()` or you call `pagetitle()` or `pagetitle(true)` in `getOrg_title()`. Using `pagetitle(false)` after changing the function like I explained, would prevent the title from `echo`ing twice.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I have changed my code by implementing your idea and got the result. Thanks again.