# PHP Unit Selenium Webdriver: How to send key by keystroke with sendKeys()

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm using the facebook webdriver with PHP Unit

Due to some filtering issues in a table I want to be able to sendKeys but key by key. 
Let's say I click on the field and I want to enter ' Selenium '

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('Sessies'))->click();
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('Selenium');
```

This would just paste ' Selenium ' in the field but I want it to type:
`S` then `e` then `l` and so on.

Is there anyway that I can do this besides:

```
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('S');
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('e');
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('l');
// and so on ...
```

EDIT: Trying out andrey's option below:

```
$var = 'Selenium';
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($var); $i++)  { 
$character = substr($var, $i,1);
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($character);     
}
```

Result = it sends the key ' m ' but that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only split word on letters and iterate over each of it. I don't know php but thinks this will look like:

```
//$var it's your word
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($var); $i++)  { 
    $character = substr($var, $i,1);
    $this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($character);     
}
```

Comment: It still put it's in all at once. It doesn't make it type letter by letter.

Comment: Add waiting time after entering letter

Comment: It's only sending the last letter ' m ' ( Selenium ) that's why it doesn't work/find anything.

Comment: $character = substr($var, $i,1); --> should become --> $character = \substr($var, $i,1); and then it works. btw how would I add a greater delay in typing the work?

Comment: Actually, `$character = $var[i]` is easier to decipher in this particular case (*i.e.* when only one character is extracted). The backslash probably isn't really required generally, [unless you're doing namespaces (wrong)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3).