# What's the purpose of '\' when we create an object?

Tags: php, object

What's the purpose of using backslash \ when we create an object in PHP?

> $iter = new \ArrayIterator($arr);

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3

Answer (score 1):

It's used to create a new object of a fully qualified class. Say, you're code is in the namespace "Namespace1":

```
namespace Namespace1;
$iter = new ArrayIterator();
```

would be resolved as `Namespace1\ArrayIterator();` and

```
$iter = new \ArrayIterator();
```

would be resolved as `ArrayIterator();`

See: http://php.net/manual/de/language.namespaces.basics.php for more infos about namespaces.