# laravel 5 models Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5, models

I have a question with model in laravel 5

I want to access my model and get return value. but that not work :(

app/Http/Controllers/MemberController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Model;
class MemberController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return MemberModel::test();
    }
}
```

app/Model/MemberModel.php

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MemberModel extends Model
{
    public function test(){
        return "123";
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('test', 'MemberController@index');
```

and error message is ..

```
FatalErrorException in MemberController.php :
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\MemberModel' not found
```

Comment: I know nothing about PHP but I'm guessing MemberController.php needs a line like `use App\Model\MemberModel;` instead of `use App\Model;` like you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are keeping your models in  Model folder 
so it should be

```
use App\Model\MemberModel;
```

Comment: nice ! that can work now , and i want to ask
i see the some code that write like this:

\MemberModel::test();

i want to know "\" have any means ?

Comment: @Maras.read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3

Answer (score 1):

there is 2 options one is you need to use namespace otherwise use that way

```
public function index()
{
    return \App\MemberModel::test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add the location to psr-4 in your composer.json

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
    }
},
```

run composer dump-autoload
you can inject the mode by name

```
use Model;
```