# Missing CreditCard Class when using Omnipay Paypal for Laravel 5

Tags: paypal, laravel-5, omnipay

Here are the repo included in my composer:

[omnipay](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay) &
[paypal](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal)

In my config/laravel-omnipay.php:

```
'gateways' => [
    'paypal' => [
        'driver'  => 'PayPal_Rest',
        'options' => [
            'solutionType'   => '',
            'landingPage'    => '',
            'headerImageUrl' => ''
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here is in my Controller:

```
// omnipay start
        $gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');

        // Initialise the gateway
        $gateway->initialize(array(
            'clientId' => 'xxxxxx',
            'secret'   => 'xxxxxx',
           'testMode' => true, // Or false when you are ready for live transactions
        ));

        // Create a credit card object
        // DO NOT USE THESE CARD VALUES -- substitute your own
        $card = new CreditCard(array(
                   'firstName'              => $request->firstname,
                   'lastName'               => $request->lastname,
                   'number'                 => $request->cardnumber,
                   'expiryMonth'            => $month_year[0],
                   'expiryYear'             => $month_year[1],
                   'cvv'                    => $request->ccv,
                   'billingAddress1'        => $request->address
                   /*
                   'billingCountry'         => 'AU',
                   'billingCity'            => 'Scrubby Creek',
                   'billingPostcode'        => '4999',
                   'billingState'           => 'QLD',*/
        ));

        // Do an authorisation transaction on the gateway
        $transaction = $gateway->authorize(array(
           'amount'        => '100',
           'currency'      => 'USD',
           'description'   => $eventName->event_title,
           'card'          => $card,
        ));
        $response = $transaction->send();
        if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
           echo "Authorize transaction was successful!\n";
           // Find the authorization ID
           $auth_id = $response->getTransactionReference();
        }
```

I've got this error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\CreditCard' not found
```

Note:  If I use RestGateway to replace PayPal_Rest, I get this error instead:

```
Class '\Omnipay\RestGateway\Gateway' not found
```

Searching an answer for a long time but didn't find a solution that works for me.  So, not entirely sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have this at the top of your class file:

```
use Omnipay\Common\CreditCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$creditCard = new \Omnipay\Common\CreditCard([...]);
```

Backslash

Further reading: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3#:~:text=%5C%20(backslash)%20is%20the%20namespace,name%20in%20the%20current%20namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3#:%7E:text=%5C%20(backslash)%20is%20the%20namespace,name%20in%20the%20current%20namespace).

The issue is because it will fetch the class from the global namespace - rather than the current namespace.