# Creating command to backup MySql database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-backups, laravel-6

I wanted to back up my database. I am using Xampp MySql. The username is root and the password is not set. I run the command using Command Prompt but it shows nothing. The Folder is created but there is nothing inside. The command prompt didn't print whether the process is a success or a failure.

**Command**

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $today = today()->format('Y-m-d');
    if (!is_dir(storage_path('backups')))
        mkdir(storage_path('backups'));

    $this->process = new Process(sprintf(
        'mysqldump --compact --skip-comments -u%s -p%s %s > %s',
        config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
        storage_path("backups/{today}.sql")
    ));
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    try {
        $this->process->mustRun();
        Log::info('Daily DB Backup - Success');
    } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
        Log::error('Daily DB Backup - Failed');
    }
}
```

Comment: There was no issue when I ran your command. You should check if there was any permission issue to save the file and check the Laravel Log if anything went wrong. The only issue was the file name on  `storage_path("backups/{today}.sql") ` 
it should be `$today`

Comment: how to open laravel log and what permissions to see. I already edited today to $today. I didnt see that one.

Comment: Laravel logs are in logs directory inside the storage directory

Comment: it says [2019-11-26 13:14:43] local.ERROR: Daily DB Backup - Failed  
@AnujShrestha

Comment: You can log the exception message rather than basic string for more information. Can you log
`\Log::error($exception->getMessage());` 
This will help to debug even further

Comment: @AnujShrestha [2019-11-26 13:46:12] local.ERROR: The command "mysqldump --compact --skip-comments -uroot -p crimson_etraining > C:\xampp\htdocs\backup_etraining\New folder\bils\storage\backups/2019-11-26.sql" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\backup_etraining\New folder\bils

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AnujShrestha what is the purpose of '\'? in \Log:error

Comment: '\' is a namespace separator. You can find more information in 
[What does a \ (backslash) do in PHP (5.3+)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3)

Seeing the error message, it looks like you cannot run the **mysqldump** command directly from the Terminal. 
If you are running on WIndows you should set up the proper environment variable to access MySQL from the terminal. So MySQL commands can be recognized by the system. I don't have much knowledge about using XAMMP in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is one great package for creating backups in Laravel: [spatie/laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup).

Comment: Hi there! May I know if I can only backup the database?

Comment: Hey there, i tried adding spatie and I can backup. I tried to view the files it dumped and it reached 2GB, i tried opening the file but the content is only my .sql. How come?

Comment: Hi! This package generates .zip archive with .sql dump of your database. If .sql file size reaches 2GB - your database contains such amount of data. 
Try checking your tables to discover which one contains huge amount of rows. Maybe your dump includes Laravel Telescope package tables.

Answer (score 1):

**Setup Your Database credential your *.env* file like this..**

```
   DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=laravel
   DB_USERNAME=root
   DB_PASSWORD=
```

**Then setup your controller function like this**

```php
    public function backup_database()
    {
        $mysqlHostName      = env('DB_HOST');
        $mysqlUserName      = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $mysqlPassword      = env('DB_PASSWORD'); 
        $DbName             = env('DB_DATABASE'); 
        $backup_name        = "backup.sql";
        $tables             = array("users", "villages", "migrations", "failed_jobs", "password_resets"); //here your tables...
    
        $connect = new \PDO("mysql:host=$mysqlHostName;dbname=$DbName;charset=utf8", "$mysqlUserName", "$mysqlPassword",array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
        $get_all_table_query = "SHOW TABLES";
        $statement = $connect->prepare($get_all_table_query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
        $output = '';
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $show_table_query = "SHOW CREATE TABLE " . $table . "";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($show_table_query);
            $statement->execute();
            $show_table_result = $statement->fetchAll();
    
            foreach($show_table_result as $show_table_row)
            {
                $output .= "\n\n" . $show_table_row["Create Table"] . ";\n\n";
            }
            $select_query = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . "";
            $statement = $connect->prepare($select_query);
            $statement->execute();
            $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
    
            for($count=0; $count<$total_row; $count++)
            {
                $single_result = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $table_column_array = array_keys($single_result);
                $table_value_array = array_values($single_result);
                $output .= "\nINSERT INTO $table (";
                $output .= "" . implode(", ", $table_column_array) . ") VALUES (";
                $output .= "'" . implode("','", $table_value_array) . "');\n";
            }
        }
        $file_name = 'database_backup_on_' . date('y-m-d') . '.sql';
        $file_handle = fopen($file_name, 'w+');
        fwrite($file_handle, $output);
        fclose($file_handle);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file_name));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file_name);
        unlink($file_name);
    }
```

**Next create you a route for accessing controller. You can download .sql backup file now.**

Answer (score 1):

Rather than write own code just use  [spatie/laravel-backup.](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/introduction)

because it provides us better approve and control. For example you can not only backup but also get notification when back success. Also you can send it to mail and compress file too.

**For backup run command on console**

```
  php artisan backup:run --only-db
```

i used `--only-db` statement because it only backup single file after compression. In my side my **server Database file size becomes 400MB** but it convert it only on **20MB**.   but if you use `php artisan backup:run` then your file size become more than 400MB.

So i am recommending you this... easy to install and use.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in a linux server setup running Laravel and MySql

```
$name = config('app.name');
$name = trim($name);
$name = Str::slug($name, '-');
$filename = $name . ".sql";

$DUMP_PATH = config('app.DUMP_PATH');
$DB_USERNAME = config('database.connections.mysql.username');
$DB_PASSWORD = config('database.connections.mysql.password');
$DB_HOST = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
$DB_PORT = config('database.connections.mysql.port');
$DB_DATABASE = config('database.connections.mysql.database');

$command = "".$DUMP_PATH." --user=" . $DB_USERNAME . " --password=" . $DB_PASSWORD . " --host=" . $DB_HOST . " " . $DB_DATABASE . "  > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
    $returnVar = NULL;
    $output = NULL;
    exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
```