# in_array value is the only value. How?

Tags: php

The second if statement in the series below keeps returning true and printing out even if `estimateId` is not the only item in the array. How do I correct this?

The goal is to **make sure only one if statement matches at all times** in the series below.

For example, right now the second if returns true when the 3rd if does. This should not happen.

```
https://localhost/data.php?estimateId=1001
https://localhost/data.php?estimateId=1001&proposalsFilter=all
```

.

```
<?php 

    # estimates/active/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimatesFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimatesFilter: ' . $_GET["estimatesFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
      print_r("<br>");

    }

    # This if keeps returning true even if estimateId is not the only item in the array?
    # estimates/1001/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/proposals/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["proposalsFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'proposalsFilter: ' . $_GET["proposalsFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/proposals/3001/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["proposalId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'proposalId: ' . $_GET["proposalId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/contracts/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["contractsFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'contractsFilter: ' . $_GET["contractsFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/contracts/3001/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["contractId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'contractId: ' . $_GET["contractId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/invoices/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["invoicesFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'invoicesFilter: ' . $_GET["invoicesFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/invoices/4001/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["invoiceId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'invoiceId: ' . $_GET["invoiceId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: `in_array` does not check if a value is the ***only*** value in any given array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> # This if keeps returning true even if estimateId is not the only item in the array?
>       # estimates/1001/

To solve your issue you can check if that value is the ***only*** value

> ```
> if(in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET))
> ```

becomes:

```
if(\count($_GET) === 1 && \in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) ){

  /***
    this will only trigger if `$_GET["estimateId"]` is in the 
    array $_GET and is the only value in the array.
   ***/
 }
```

Which checks the values and also checks a [`count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) of values in the array. Because you are looking for just this value, the array count should only be 1.

> https://localhost/data.php?estimateId=1001

Above returns true because $_GET contains only one value.

> https://localhost/data.php?estimateId=1001&proposalsFilter=all

Above returns false because $_GET array contains 2 values.

Comment: Right on Martin. Can you comment on the backslashes?

Comment: @ASPiRE please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3)

Answer (score -1):

"The goal is to make sure only one if statement matches at all times in the series below."

Simply use elseif instead of if then.

```
<?php 

    # estimates/active/
    if (in_array($_GET["estimatesFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimatesFilter: ' . $_GET["estimatesFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
      print_r("<br>");

    }

    # This if keeps returning true even if estimateId is not the only item in the array?
    # estimates/1001/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/proposals/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["proposalsFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'proposalsFilter: ' . $_GET["proposalsFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/proposals/3001/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["proposalId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'proposalId: ' . $_GET["proposalId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/contracts/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["contractsFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'contractsFilter: ' . $_GET["contractsFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/contracts/3001/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["contractId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'contractId: ' . $_GET["contractId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/invoices/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["invoicesFilter"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'invoicesFilter: ' . $_GET["invoicesFilter"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

    # estimates/1001/invoices/4001/
    elseif (in_array($_GET["estimateId"], $_GET) && in_array($_GET["invoiceId"], $_GET)) {

        print_r('estimateId: ' . $_GET["estimateId"] . ' & ' . 'invoiceId: ' . $_GET["invoiceId"] . ' url parameter(s) was passed.');
        print_r("<br>");

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: this does not work because `in_array` does not check if a value is the ***only*** value in any given array