# When do we put \ before Exception , and when not?

Tags: php

Sometimes I find codes using the antislash when catching exception : `catch(\Exception $e)`, and sometimes there is no antislash ! So what is the difference ?

Comment: I would suggest you gen up on [PHP Namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: I think this is a more useful answer about backslashes in namespaces for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-a-backslash-do-in-php-5-3