# Backslash in PHP -- what does it mean?

Tags: php

I just saw the use of a backslash in a reference to a PHP object and was curious about it (I have never seen this before). What does it mean?

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
```

If you're curious, here's [SendGrid's documentation](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/php-email-example-using-smtp/).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075521/backslash-syntax-when-creating-objects, so you can find your answer there.

Comment: @11684 yea just saw that...oops

Comment: This great post explains in much more detail http://stackoverflow.com/q/4790020/6521116

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's because they're using [PHP namespaces](http://php.net/language.namespaces). Namespaces are new as of PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 19):

It's PHP's namespace operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php.

Don't ask why it's a backslash. It's (imho) the stupidest possible choice they could have made, basing their decisions on a highly slanted/bigoted scoring system that made sense only to the devs.

Comment: Well, backslash was best available choice (would you want to use `:::` or `->->`?).

Comment: That could work too, but `->Hello->something()` would look ugly. And I don't think PHP would like having operator mean two things at once (especially so different, when I would see `Abc->def()` for first time I would think it's method of constant `Abc`).

Comment: They shouldn't have used the dot operator for string concat, what a waste for a good namespace operator!

Comment: Check RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaceseparator for how they chose Backslash.

Comment: I'm so going to create an `n` namespace! But seriously... if you can separate folders and files with `/`, why not separate namespaces and classes with `::`?

Answer (score 9):

This is syntax for namespaces. You can read more about namespaces at [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). They they require at least PHP 5.3.

For example:

```
namespace SendGrid;
function Mail() {
    // You can access this function by using SendGrid\Mail() externally
}
```