# Symfony2.4.0 new backward slash classname()

Tags: php, symfony

I'm not sure if this is specifically Symfony2.4.0 related, but when I have a

```
<?php
namespace Wow\DogeBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
class ProbeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this ->setName('a:name')
             ->setDescription('wow');
    }
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {    
        $whenithappened = new \DateTime();
        //more code
    }
}
```

This code works alright, but what does the backward slash in front of DateTime() mean? As soon as I remove the backward slash I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Wow\DogeBundle\Command\DateTime'
```

Is the backward slash some sort of escape to go back to the root namespace? I can have this code

```
<?php
$whenithappened = new \DateTime();
var_dump($whenithappened);
?>
```

which works fine with or without the backward slash in front of `DateTime()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash in PHP -- what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788400/backslash-in-php-what-does-it-mean), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790020/what-does-backslash-do-php5-3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: I originally had this question posted as forwards slash, so googling for an answer yielded no results. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespacing allows you to define your own classes with the same names as PHP's built in classes, so you could have (all in one file):-

```
namespace my\name

class DateTime
{
    //some code here
}

$myDateTime = new DateTime(); // <- uses your DateTime class
$dateTime = new \DateTime();  // <- uses PHP's built in DateTime class.
```

[see it working](http://3v4l.org/Cj71E).

So the `\` is telling PHP to use the root namespace rather than yours.You are correct that there are times when you don't need it, but it is a good habit to get into to avoid hard to track bugs later on.

Comment: If you add a use statement for the root DateTime class, then you can instantiate it without the /.

Comment: @catchamonkey Yes, that is true, but the question is specifically about using `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a namespace in the beginning of the file, calling `new DateTime()` will look for a class with name `DateTime` in the same namepace, this will return an error. With `new \DateTime()`, PHP will search for this classes in its base classes.

Your last exemple works because it uses no namespace, there is no ambiguity for finding the `DateTime` class.