# What is the difference between "/" and "\" in Laravel/PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering what would be the difference between Forward Slash "/" and Backslash "\" in php and Laravel. 
For example in every controller you have:

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

but if there was Forward slash instead of Backslash, it does not work:

`use Illuminate/Http/Request;`

and it throws an error:

> "syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';'"

Comment: The difference is one is correct syntax, the other isn't.

Comment: @Jonnix yeah that's obvious, but is there something more to it than just syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788400/backslash-in-php-what-does-it-mean

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "more than just syntax"? Example?

Comment: PHP, and most coding languages, have specific syntax, and symbols are not interchangeable. `/` is not the same as \, just as `//` is not the same as \\

Comment: As pointed out, the namespace in PHP syntax requires the backslash separator.  I just want to point out that this should not be confused with the path separator `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` which can be '/' or '\' depending on the operating system.  PHP doesn't care if you use the '/' or '\' for these paths, regardless of operating system.

Comment: @Jonnix I wasn't expecting it to be that simple, I taught there might be some deeper programming concepts involved or something.

Comment: Escape sequences, introduced by '\' in most languages.
UNC share volumes in windows begin with two '\\'.
URL uses two '//' after the colon.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are always separated by backslash. It's the defined separator.

You can read it here in the documentation of php:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Some more information you'll find in the FAQ for namespaces:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php