# How to call php psliwa image optimizer

Tags: php, image, optimization

I'm trying to use this php script for image-optimization: https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer

But I think that the documentation is very poor, this is all what it says:

```
$factory = new \ImageOptimizer\OptimizerFactory();
$optimizer = $factory->get();

$filepath = /* path to image */;

$optimizer->optimize($filepath);
```

But I really don't understand this way of calling a class with "new \" and get this error when I copy that code: Fatal error: Class 'ImageOptimizer\OptimizerFactory' not found in...
What is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backslash in PHP -- what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788400/backslash-in-php-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backslash syntax when creating objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075521/backslash-syntax-when-creating-objects)

Comment: I read those post but I still don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I cannot call correctly the image optimizer class. That is my problem, and that was my question. Sorry I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

If you are at a loss and the composer library install isn't working for you, you can just call every one of the libraries from your install folder.  It's a dirty way of doing it with composer being so convenient, but will work.

Add this to the top of your image processing file:

```
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/Optimizer.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/OptimizerFactory.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/CommandOptimizer.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/Command.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/SuppressErrorOptimizer.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/ChainOptimizer.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/SmartOptimizer.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/TypeGuesser/TypeGuesser.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/TypeGuesser/SmartTypeGuesser.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/TypeGuesser/GdTypeGuesser.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/TypeGuesser/ExtensionTypeGuesser.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/Exception/Exception.php";
require "your_path/ImageOptimizer/Exception/CommandNotFound.php";
```

... and then call the methods as described:

```
$factory = new \ImageOptimizer\OptimizerFactory();
$optimizer = $factory->get();

$filepath = /* path to image */;

$optimizer->optimize($filepath);
//optimized file overwrites original one
```

SOURCE: https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer

Comment: I've just realised how old that question was

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the "composer library install" that you mention? I found very poor the documentation of the library.